# How to zeroize this div?

Tags: css

I want to zeroize this ".wrapper wf" class. (like header and .p) But I can not succeed, could you help me to figure it out?

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x65AA/1/)

```
.wf{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}




#products.list .img_wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 177px;
    height: 95px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to cover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not about alignment,`<ul>` has a padding on default so you need to remove that padding, add this style to your CSS:

```
ul{
    padding:0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/x65AA/2/)